# Rename sequence of elements if it occurs more than once (R, dplyr)

Tags: r, list, loops, data.table

I have a dataset, df

```
 ID         Date
 A          9/9/2019 5:00:01
 A          9/9/2019 5:00:02
 A          9/9/2019 5:00:03
 B          9/9/2019 6:00:01
 B          9/9/2019 6:00:03
 B          9/9/2019 6:00:04
 A          9/9/2019 6:00:05
 A          9/9/2019 6:00:06
 A          9/9/2019 6:00:07
 c          9/9/2019 6:00:08
 c          9/9/2019 6:00:09
 A          9/9/2019 6:00:10
 A          9/9/2019 6:00:11
```

I would like

```
 ID         Date
 A          9/9/2019 5:00:01
 A          9/9/2019 5:00:02
 A          9/9/2019 5:00:03
 B          9/9/2019 6:00:01
 B          9/9/2019 6:00:03
 B          9/9/2019 6:00:04
 list1      9/9/2019 6:00:05
 list1      9/9/2019 6:00:06
 list1      9/9/2019 6:00:07
 c          9/9/2019 6:00:08
 c          9/9/2019 6:00:09
 list2      9/9/2019 6:00:10
 list2      9/9/2019 6:00:11
```

I would like to rename a sequence of elements if it occurs more than once in my dataset

**dput:**

```
structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "B", "c"), class =   "factor"), 
Date = structure(1:13, .Label = c("9/9/2019 12:00:00 AM", 
"9/9/2019 12:00:01 AM", "9/9/2019 12:00:02 AM", "9/9/2019    12:00:03 AM", 
"9/9/2019 12:00:04 AM", "9/9/2019 12:00:05 AM", "9/9/2019   12:00:06 AM", 
"9/9/2019 12:00:07 AM", "9/9/2019 12:00:08 AM", "9/9/2019 12:00:09 AM", 
"9/9/2019 12:00:11 AM", "9/9/2019 12:00:12 AM", "9/9/2019 12:00:13 AM"
), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))
```

This is what I have tried:

```
c(letters, do.call(paste0, expand.grid(letters, 1:1000)))
setDT(df[, grp := rleid(ID)][ItemSubject == "", 
ItemSubject := nm1[.GRP], grp][, grp := NULL][]
```

I was using this command prior, but not sure to integrate this particular command within the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following approach is relatively clean:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DT)

DT[ , run_id := rleid(ID)]
DT[DT[ , .SD[1L], by = run_id][duplicated(ID), ID := paste0('list', .I)],
   on = 'run_id', ID := i.ID][]
#         ID                    Date run_id
#     <fctr>                  <fctr>  <int>
#  1:      A    9/9/2019 12:00:00 AM      1
#  2:      A    9/9/2019 12:00:01 AM      1
#  3:      A    9/9/2019 12:00:02 AM      1
#  4:      B 9/9/2019    12:00:03 AM      2
#  5:      B    9/9/2019 12:00:04 AM      2
#  6:      B    9/9/2019 12:00:05 AM      2
#  7:  list1  9/9/2019   12:00:06 AM      3
#  8:  list1    9/9/2019 12:00:07 AM      3
#  9:  list1    9/9/2019 12:00:08 AM      3
# 10:      c    9/9/2019 12:00:09 AM      4
# 11:      c    9/9/2019 12:00:11 AM      4
# 12:  list2    9/9/2019 12:00:12 AM      5
# 13:  list2    9/9/2019 12:00:13 AM      5
```

The data is fundamentally ordered across rows -- the series of `A` rows 1-3 is *different* from the series of `A` rows 7-9.

This hints that `rleid` will have to play a role. `rleid` generates an ID for each *series* that I think conforms to the structure you have in mind for the data set.

Now, we can approach your problem. As you describe it, we want to replace the `ID` column whenever `run_id` has increased but `ID` has repeated.

The approach I took is to try and use `duplicated` to detect repeats. The issue is that in the original table, there are repeats of `A` (e.g. rows 
2 & 3) that aren't repeats in the sense we mean. We want to reduce the table into a single row *per `run_id`* first so that duplicates mean duplicates *across `run_id`s*. That's what the `DT[ , .SD[1L], by = run_id]` part does. Note that strictly speaking, we could do `DT[ , .(ID = ID[1L]), by = run_id]` since we don't need the `Date` column.

Now, we can use `duplicated(ID)` to identify the rows which are repeats; since the second argument (commonly referred to as `j`) is evaluated *after* the filter `duplicated(ID)` happens, there are only two rows left, therefore `.I` lines up perfectly with the counter you wanted in the replacement.

Once this is done, we can replace the target `ID` values in the original table by *joining back* and overwriting (aka *update-on-join*).

Comment: wow this worked! I will try this on my large dataset now. Is this essentially a loop?

Comment: @tanishahudson everything's a loop at some level  in seriousness, I would focus on what to take away in terms of how to think about data structure, there are a few big ideas here: (1) time series/ordered data (2) aggregation (3) uniqueness (4) joins

Answer (score 2):

In `base R`, we can do this with `rle`

```
df1$ID <- inverse.rle(within.list(rle(as.character(df1$ID)),  {
           i1 <- duplicated(values)
           values[i1] <- paste0("list", seq_len(sum(i1)))
            }))
df1
#      ID                    Date
#1      A    9/9/2019 12:00:00 AM
#2      A    9/9/2019 12:00:01 AM
#3      A    9/9/2019 12:00:02 AM
#4      B 9/9/2019    12:00:03 AM
#5      B    9/9/2019 12:00:04 AM
#6      B    9/9/2019 12:00:05 AM
#7  list1  9/9/2019   12:00:06 AM
#8  list1    9/9/2019 12:00:07 AM
#9  list1    9/9/2019 12:00:08 AM
#10     c    9/9/2019 12:00:09 AM
#11     c    9/9/2019 12:00:11 AM
#12 list2    9/9/2019 12:00:12 AM
#13 list2    9/9/2019 12:00:13 AM
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another `data.table` option:

```
DT[, nid := rleid(ID)][, 
    ri := rleid(nid), ID][
        ri > 1L, ID := paste0("list", ri - 1L), ID]
```

output:

```
       ID                    Date nid ri
 1:     A    9/9/2019 12:00:00 AM   0  1
 2:     A    9/9/2019 12:00:01 AM   0  1
 3:     A    9/9/2019 12:00:02 AM   0  1
 4:     B 9/9/2019    12:00:03 AM   1  1
 5:     B    9/9/2019 12:00:04 AM   1  1
 6:     B    9/9/2019 12:00:05 AM   1  1
 7: list1  9/9/2019   12:00:06 AM   2  2
 8: list1    9/9/2019 12:00:07 AM   2  2
 9: list1    9/9/2019 12:00:08 AM   2  2
10:     c    9/9/2019 12:00:09 AM   3  1
11:     c    9/9/2019 12:00:11 AM   3  1
12: list2    9/9/2019 12:00:12 AM   4  3
13: list2    9/9/2019 12:00:13 AM   4  3
```